# Is it true that if the product of elements of two sets, and sum of elements are the same, then the two sets are the same?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, permutations

We wish to either show the following or find a counterexample:

> For any two sets of positive integers $A$ and $B$, if $|A| = |B|$, $\sum_{a \in A}^{}a = \sum_{b \in B}^{}b$,  and $\prod_{a \in A}^{}a = \prod_{b \in B}^{}b$
>   then $A = B$

The converse of the statement above is is certainly true, but the truth of the actual conjecture is not obvious.

An equivalent way to express the conjecture is as follows:

> Let $S$ and $T$ be finite sequences of positive integers, and let them be the same length. Also, no integer can appear more than once a given sequence. If $\sum_{x \in S}^{}x = \sum_{y \in T}^{}y$ and $\prod_{x \in S}^{}x = \prod_{y \in T}^{}y$ then sequence $S$ is a permutation of sequence $T$

If the conjecture is correct, then the following algorithm will correctly determine whether two one-dimensional arrays of distinct positive integers contain the same elements:

```
DEFINE FUNCTION permutation_check(ARRAY A, ARRAY B)

    DOUBLE FLOAT acum_log <- 0; // accumulator of logorithmic evaluations
    INT          acum     <- 0; // accumulator 

    FOR i = 1 to A.last_index
        a  <- a  + A[i]  - B[i]

        acum_log <- acum_log + LOG(A[i]) - LOG(B[i])
    END_FOR

    IF (a != 0 or ABSOLUTE_VALUE(acum_log) > 0.0001)
        RETURN "A is NOT a permutation of B"; // certainly correct
    END_IF

    RETURN "A is a permutation of B"; // dubious

END FUNCTION DEFINTION
```

Comment: Consider the roots of the polynomials $x^3-3x^2+7x-100$ and $x^3-3x^2-20x-100$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio wrote, "Consider the roots of the polynomial $x^3−3*x^2+7*x−100 = 0$" However, the set of real root to that polynomial only contains one element, and it is $x ≈ 5.271115886$. That is not an integer. I am only concerned with sets of positive integers. Also, I am mainly interested in sets containing more than one element.

Comment: All right, the roots of those polynomials are not positive integers, but they can be made so by a little tweaking. I thought the main idea was clear: just two constraints (on $\sum$ and $\prod$) stand no chance of fixing a whole subset of $\mathbb{N}^+$ with cardinality $\geq 3$.

Comment: On the other hand, this spawns an interesting question about polynomials, i.e. to find two monic third-degree polynomials with positive integer roots, having $mx$ as difference.

Comment: Then 5xum answer can be read as: $x^3-20x^2+81x-90$ and $x^3-20x^2+109x-90$ do the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My initial gut feeling was "I'd bet my left kidney that can't be true". Why? Because you only set **two** constraints, which might well be enough if you only have two variables (and it turns out, it is), but you have **no limitation** on the number of variables. Clearly, that can't be true in the reals, and sure $\mathbb N$ is a little more restrictive, but still. I'd bet even just $3$ elements can give a counterexample.

---

Turns out the gut feeling was right, the answer is **No**. Take $\{1,9,10\}$ and $\{2,3,15\}$ as a counterexample.

If you are curious, here's the python code I used to find this counterexample (it's a simple brute force search)

```
def find_counter(n):
    sum_prod = {}
    for a in range(1, n):
        for b in range(a+1, n):
            for c in range(b+1, n):
                s = a + b + c
                p = a * b * c
                if (s,p) in sum_prod:
                    return sum_prod[(s,p)], (a,b,c)
                sum_prod[(s,p)] = (a,b,c)

find_counter(100)
```

Comment: Π {1, 9,10} = 90 = Π {2, 3,15} . . . . . Σ{2, 3,15} = 20 = Σ {1, 9,10} = 20 Yes! your counterexample works!

Comment: this is a minimal counter example, in the sense that n=2 works

Comment: @MCT Indeed. Which is why I did a brute force search for $3$-element sets :)

Comment: @5xum I accidentally pressed the return key on my keyboard before I was finished writing my comment. I thought I was inserting a linebreak, not submitting the comment. I had more to say than just $1*9*10 = 90$

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone I see now. So if my counterexample works, I suggest you accept my answer. (By the way, a little playing around helped me find "even better" counterexamples where more than $2$ sets give the same product and sum. For example, [(15, 88, 140), (16, 77, 150), (20, 55, 168), (24, 44, 175), (25, 42, 176)] is an example of $5$ sets that all give the same sum and product.

Comment: When you have sets of three, you can add a common element to each set to get a set of four - these are clearly not disjoint, while sets of three necessarily are.

Comment: "Better" examples: 3 sets: sum 39, product $1200=2^43\cdot5^2$, (20,15,4), (24,10,5), (25,8,6). 4 sets: sum 118, product $37800=2^33^35^27$, (54,50,14), (63,40,15), (70,30,18), (72,25,21). 5 sets: sum 185, product $83160=2^33^35\cdot7\cdot11$, (90,84,11), (110,63,12), (126,44,15), (132,35,18), (135,28,22). For $6,\dots10$ sets the minimal sums are 400, 511, 1022, 1287, 2574 and corresp (not nec. minimal) products 846720, 1965600, 15724800, 34927200, 279417600.

Answer (score 1):

The sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{6\}$ are a counterexample to your first conjecture. The second conjecture is not equivalent to the first, as this counterexample shows.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, the two sets contain the same number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just to highlight another method, I simply considered the factorisations of various numbers with lots of factors. I was aiming for a counter-example with three integers.

So with product $36$ I found $2,3,6$ and $3,3,4$, the second of which is not strictly a set, because it has duplicates. But its existence suggested that in larger cases there might be distinct integers. There is also $1,6,6$ and $2,2,9$.

$60$ and $84$ gave nothing, but $72$ had $2,6,6$ and $3,3,8$ and $96$ yielded $1,8,12$ and $2,3,16$.

This was quite quick by hand.

Two further questions suggest themselves: are there examples of three sets of three positive integers having the same sum and the same product? Are there examples of two sets of $n$ positive integers having the same sum and the same product for all $n\ge 3$? Both seem likely based on my hand calculations.

Comment: And one of the other answers indeed finds five sets of three with the same sum and product.

Comment: "are there examples of three sets of three positive integers having the same sum and the same product?".... here's an example of *five* :) $\{15, 88, 140\}, \{16, 77, 150\}, \{20, 55, 168\}, \{24, 44, 175\}, \{25, 42, 176\}$. I think the real question is "are there examples of $n$ sets of three positive numbers all with the same sum and product?".

Comment: @5xum Indeed. I am wondering whether there is enough structure to prove that you can find arbitrarily many sets of three, or whether the irregularity of the primes gets in the way too much. I now see that from a set of three I can get a set of four simply by adding a common element to each set. Also a constant multiple of any collection of sets is a solution. If I could multiply all my sets of three by some common factor in such a way that I could construct an another set with the same common sum, I'd be there.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$ it certainly is true. If $n=2$, the claim is true. It says
$$a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2 \text{ and } a_1a_2 = b_1b_2 \implies a_1 = b_{1}, a_2 = b_{2}$$
where $a_1< a_2, b_1 < b_2$. This in turn implies
$$(a_1 + a_2)^2 = (b_1 + b_2)^2 \implies a_1^2 + a_2^2 = b_1^2 + b_2^2.$$
WLOG suppose that $a_2 \geq b_2$, so let $a_2 = b_2 + k$ for $k \geq 0$. Then
$$a_1^2 + 2kb_2 + k^2 = b_1^2$$
$$a_1 = b_1 - k.$$
Plugging in the second into the first gives
$$2k^2 = 0$$
hence $k=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, the two sets contain the same number of elements.